# .Net Set Child Form Height From Percentage Of Parent Height

Tags: .net, vb.net

I'm trying to set the height of my Mdi Child form to 25% of the height of the parent container form and dock to the bottom left.

Currently I have this code.

```
test.Size = New Size(Me.Width = Me.Width - 90%, Me.Height = Me.Height - 75%)
test.Dock = DockStyle.Left
```

This does affect the height but its not the expected results, this only takes of a small rectangle from the right side of the form.
 [Here you can see the effect of the current code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Os7J.png)

**UPDATE**

[This is the result with the new code.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YJDyK.png)

```
test.Width = Me.ClientSize.Width * 0.1     
test.Height = Me.ClientSize.Height * 0.25
```

I would like it to be docked at the bottom right, is that possible?

Comment: Questions are problem based, not project based.  If you have a *new* problem or question, create a new post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `test` is the MDI child instance, and `Me` is the MDI parent instance:

```
test.Width = Me.ClientSize.Width * 0.1     ' 10% of parent
test.Height = Me.ClientSize.Height * 0.25  '  25% of parent
```

Typically the `Dock` property when not set to `None` will override your custom sizes.  I don't know how it affects an MDI child form.

I would just set the `Top` and `Left` properties.

Comment: Thank you for that. Will have to have a look into the Me.ClientSize. I have updated the post, please check it. I need to dock to the bottom right. Thats all, thanks very much

Comment: Set the `Top` and `Left` properties.